Spawn transaction from trigger
I'm struggling with triggers and indirect tables I need to mess with.
Context: we have an old app whose backend we can't change but I have full access to the database.
This app is inserting one row in table A, then several rows in tables B, C, D.
I need to DELETE some rows from B, C, D that shouldn't be there ONLY when the user is inserting a row in A.
I created an AFTER INSERT trigger for A, hoping to be able to delete rows in B, C, D.
That didn't work, I even used WAITFOR DELAY long enough to wait for rows in B, C, D but apparently those are not visible when the trigger is running. My guess is that until the transaction that inserted in A commits everything those new rows in B, C, D are not visible.
The question then is: what is the best way to DELETE these rows in tables B, C, D at the time of inserting in A?
Is there a way to spawn an independent transaction that waits until it sees the rows in B, C, D and then deletes them?

If you are doing multiple INSERTs one after the other, then your TRIGGER is going to trigger too early. If you INSERT into A, have a trigger to delete rows from B, and then INSERT those rows into B, then the rows will still be there; you deleted before you INSERTed. Your DELETE needs to be the last thing you do. Perhaps you need AFTER INSERT statements on B, C, and D?

The insert won't be finished until the trigger finishes, so the longer delay you put into it, the longer you have to wait without achieving the result.

Can you bind together afterwards which rows to delete by some ID? What if someone uses multiple copies of the program and insert some interleaving rows.

Why don't you put the trigger on B C and D? An INSTEAD OF trigger might be better, choosing not to insert those rows.

We'll the thing is I only need to delete the extra records (on certain condition) when creating the row for A.
If the transaction that creates A is complete. I must be able to let the user create an "invalid" record in B, C, or D.  So unless I figure out how to know for certain that A was created before this transaction an INSTEAD OF trigger would PREVENT the user from adding an "invalid" record in B, C, or D.
Not easy I know...

Does the application use same session / connection for it's A,B,C,D operations? then you could probably track the insert sequence by @@spid and do your logic in the triggers

Well you can just join back on to that A record surely, to check if it's present? You can also track using SESSION_CONTEXT

When the insert occurs in table A, create a queue record that is processed by a background task to clean up associated records in B,C,D after a reasonable delay.

I thought of that but the DB is in Azure, and then you have either to pay for the equivalent of an SQL Agent or run a cron statement from outside...
I may take this route if it can't be done from inside the DB..
Thanks for pointing out.

Managed Instance supports Service Broker queues and SQL Agent, for Azure SQL Database you would need Elastic Database Jobs, Logic App, Azure Automation, or an Azure Function.

Well I finally settled for a workaround involving the user as he's the one requesting this.
I set two triggers on table A:

AFTER INSERT to push new records on an auxiliary table in order to capture de creation time of record A (table A had a single field for creation/update time)
AFTER UPDATE to go on and delete all mismatching records from tables B, C, D that belong to record A and have less than 20 seconds between record A creation (saved in aux table) and creation/update time for corresponding records in B, C, D

The app has an "update" for record A, so that simplifies the whole process.
The 20 seconds is safety window for the original transaction to finish and to allow the user to willingly insert or keep a modified mismatching record in tables B, C, D that he needs. The whole purpose was to remove the defaulted mismatching records since they were a lot them while he might only need to keep a few.
Want to delete all mismatching records? just hit update.
Want to keep some? Wait 20seconds, edit records on B, C, or D, and then update record A.
Although my particular problem has been "solved" I keep thinking if there's an elegant solution for this situation that can be solved from the DB...
Maybe it's just bluntly out of scope for what a DB should be able to do...
Thanks to everyone for your prompt support and suggestions.
